# asynchronous calls tracking

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous

**I am interested to find gaps in the solution to handle asynchronous calls chaining  in silverlight. Please let me know if you find gaps/issues in the solution. Alternatively, if there is another way/pattern to solve the problem, please point me to the right direction.**

Code is not compiled or tested

**Problem**

We have a requirement to do some action after a bunch of asynchronous calls are finished.

For example assign default values to UI controls once service calls are finished.

```
void Fun()
{
    Servicecall1();
    Servicecall2();

    //Make sure the following is executed only after the previous async calls are finished.
    AssignDefaultValues();
}
```

**Solution**

One way to do this is chaining the service calls through callbacks. However, I am just wondering how bad/good it is trying to achieve it through an object of a special asynchronous  execution tracking class like below.

```
class SomeClass
{
   AsyncMehodCallWatcher _methodcallwatcher = new AsyncMehodCallWatcher();            

        void fun()
        {
         _methodcallwatcher.AsyncMethodStartMultipleCall(() => 
           {
             //this function will be called automatically after the following service calls
             AssignDefaultValues();
            }, 2);

         Servicecall1();
         Servicecall2();
        }

        void Servicecall1()
        {
           serviceclient.DoSomething(DoSomethingcallback);

        }

        void DoSomethingcallback(object sender, GetCompletedEventArgs arg)
        {
           _methodcallwatcher.AsyncCallCompleted();
        }

        void Servicecall2()
        {
           serviceclient.DoSomething(DoSomething2callback);

        }

        void DoSomething2callback(object sender, GetCompletedEventArgs arg)
        {
           _methodcallwatcher.AsyncCallCompleted();
        }
}
```

Anyone who need to call Servicecall1(), or Servicecall2() should call AsyncMethodPreCall(null).

And here is the proposed implementation of AsyncMehodCallWatcher

```
 public class AsyncMehodCallWatcher 
    {
        private int _counter = 0;

        public AsyncMehodCallWatcher()
        {
        }

        public void AsyncMethodPreCall()
        {
            AsyncMethodPreCall(null);
        }

        Action _callcompletedaction = null;      

        public void AsyncMethodStartMultipleCall(Action action, int numofcalls)
        {
            if (action != null)
            {
                if (_callcompletedaction != null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(LocalString.AsyncMehodCallWatcherErrorAsyncCalls);
                }

                _callcompletedaction = action;             
                _counter = numofcalls;
            }
        }

        public void AsyncMethodPreCall(Action action)
        {
            if (action != null)
            {
                if (_callcompletedaction != null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(LocalString.AsyncMehodCallWatcherErrorAsyncCalls);
                }
                _callcompletedaction = action;               
            }
            _counter++;           
        }

        public void AsyncCallCompleted()
        {
            _counter--;

            if (_counter < 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(LocalString.AsyncMehodCallWatcherErrorAsyncCalls);
            }

            if (_counter == 0)
            { 
                if (_callcompletedaction != null)
                {
                    _callcompletedaction();
                    _callcompletedaction = null;                
                }
            }         
        }

    }
```

Comment: For the problem mentioned, is the proposed solution acceptable or any other way is there?

Comment: Are you targeting Silverlight < v4? Otherwise, I think you're re-inventing the wheel, use [TPL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/task-parallel-library/info) and possibly [`async/await`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info) (recommended).

Comment: @Noseratio, important thing here is , our services client works through a callback mechanism, as you can see in the example. ie, you pass a callback with the servicescall, and the client will callback once the action finishes. I am not sure how can TPL help in this scenario.

Comment: Jimmy, it can help very much with `TaskCompletionSource`, which you'd use from your callback and call `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult` from there. Then you could use compositions like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx) or `async/await`. You do re-invent the wheel here. As time allows, I'll post an answer showing how your code might be re-factored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I meant in the comments to the question:

```
Task<GetCompletedEventArgs> CallServiceAsync(
    Action<Action<object, GetCompletedEventArgs> callDoSomething)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<GetCompletedEventArgs>();
    callDoSomething((sender, arg) => tcs.SetResult(arg));
    return tcs.Task;
}

async Task AsyncMethodStartMultipleCall(ServiceClient client)
{
    var task1 = CallServiceAsync((callback) => client.DoSomething(callback));
    var task2 = CallServiceAsync((callback) => client.DoSomething(callback));
    var task3 = CallServiceAsync((callback) => client.DoSomething(callback));

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
}
```

I highly recommend using [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async) for Silverlight 4 and .NET 4.0. It will give you `async/await`, if you use VS2012+. If you can't use that for any reason, use `ContinueWhenAll` or go for a composition like [`Then` pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx) by Stephen Toub, if the order of completion matters. Example:

```
Task AsyncMethodStartMultipleCall(ServiceClient client)
{
    var task1 = CallServiceAsync((callback) => client.DoSomething(callback));
    var task2 = CallServiceAsync((callback) => client.DoSomething(callback));
    var task3 = CallServiceAsync((callback) => client.DoSomething(callback));

    return TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll(new [] { task1, task2, task3 }, (tasks) => 
    {
        Debug.Print("All completed!");
    });
}
```

If you're not going to `use async/await`, make sure you save `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` from the UI thread, and pass it to `ContinueWhenAll` or `ContinueWith`, otherwise your continuation lambda might be called on a pool thread.

Comment: @Noserito, please note we are still in .net 4, still no async and await

Comment: @Jimmy, I highly recommend using [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async) for Silverlight 4 and .NET 4.0. It will give you `async/await`, if you use VS2012+. If you can't use that for any reason, go for [`Then` pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx) by Stephen Toub.

Comment: @Noserito, unfortunately we are still in 2010. Hopefully we will upgrade soon. For now, follow Stephen Toub's method

Comment: @Jimmy, I've updated it for VS2010. You can learn about tasks here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/task-parallel-library/info

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Task Parallel Library you can turn your callback based methods into Task based methods using the TaskCompletionSource. Here is an example.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public async Task Fun()
    {
        // execute both service requests at the same time
        Task<Result> fooTask = ServiceCallAsync1();
        Task<Result> barTask = ServiceCallAsync2();

        // wait for both of them to be complete.
        Result[] t = await Task.WhenAll(new[] { fooTask, barTask });
        AssignDefaultValues();
    }

    public Task<Result> ServiceCallAsync1()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<Result> completion = new TaskCompletionSource<Result>();
        serviceclient.DoSomething(() =>
        {
            completion.SetResult(new FooResult());
        });
        return completion.Task;
    }

    public Task<Result> ServiceCallAsync2()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<Result> completion = new TaskCompletionSource<Result>();
        serviceclient.DoSomething(() =>
        {
            completion.SetResult(new BarResult());
        });
        return completion.Task;
    }

    private void AssignDefaultValues()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: please note we are still in .net 4, so no async and await

Comment: Oh but you can! You can use the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) nuget package!